# Finding a specific sequence

Tags: excel

In Excel, I'm trying to find the longest sequence amongst a column of numbers, in this case a zero. I'm trying this

```
{=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF('All Games'!K2:K5066=0,ROW('All Games'!K2:K5066)), IF('All Games'!K2:K5066=1, ROW('All Games'!K2:K5066))))}
```

It isn't working, and returns 11. The most zero's I can find in sequence is 6.

Comment: Do you have blanks?  Your formula will count blanks as zero's.

Comment: No. No blanks. I've used a simple helper column (o) to find the answer.

=IF(K2<>0,0,IF(K3=0,1+O3,0))
copied down then in next column
=MAX(O:O)
=MATCH(N2,O1:O2550,0)

It works. Not what I was after but at least I understand this formula.